# How to speed up LBP texture matching

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm doing texture matching where I need to match a texture with my "database". The Local Binary Pattern (LBP) histogram can be 2^16 in length since I use 16 neighbors. The problem is the matching is getting slower when the database is bigger where currently it contains 100+ images. Anyone know how to speed up this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a heirarchy in the image database and avoid template matching with all images.
You can use [this idea](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/711175) for it.

Otherwise, you can try to [reduce the dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) of the LBP histogram. You can even think of using some other technique (like [Gabor transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_transform)) on the LBP image to extract feature. Google tells me that it has been used greatly for texture analysis.